# Getting id of worker from inside worker process

Tags: node.js

Using the node.js Cluster module, it is straightforward to get the id of a worker process.

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

that would be:

```
cluster.on('fork', function (worker) {
    console.log('A worker', worker.id, 'was forked.');
});
```

but how can I get the `id` of the worker from inside the worker itself? How come the cluster module doesn't give the worker an id when the cluster forks the worker?

Do I really have to send the worker it's cluster id from the master process?

I am looking for something akin to:

`process.id` (as opposed to process.pid)

or

```
process.worker.id
```

in any case, I am having trouble figuring out what the id of the worker is from inside the worker itself.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log('I am master');
  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
  console.log('I am worker #' + cluster.worker.id);
}
```

as in [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_worker)